# Freeform Next errors

Tags: solspace-freeform-next

I get these errors when submitting a Solspace Freeform Next form. The submission is successful. Record is made, notifications are sent properly. Everything works otherwise.

EE 5.3.2 Freeform Next Light 1.8.3

L.

```
Notice

Trying to access array offset on value of type null

user/addons/freeform_next/vendor/egulias/email-validator/src/Egulias/EmailValidator/Parser/Parser.php, line 132

Severity: E_NOTICE
Warning

Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ee/legacy/core/Exceptions.php:120)

ee/legacy/core/Input.php, line 238

Severity: E_WARNING
Warning

Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ee/legacy/core/Exceptions.php:120)

user/addons/freeform_next/Utilities/Plugin.php, line 57

Severity: E_WARNING
```

Comment: I don't know what cause is, but just to let you know I've seen the same error with Freeform Next Pro 1.8.3 on EE5.3.2, and it has been around at least since 1.8.3 was released in December 2019...  Since these are just php warnings they will only show up if you are logged in as admin - and they don't appear to have any adverse consequences for the function of the add-on, you probably can ignore it.  However does underline fact that it appears that Freeform Pro is drifting into abandonware status.  :(

Comment: @JCOGSDesign Not abandonware. This is the first time we've ever had anyone report this issue to us. Perhaps it affects only certain environments - haven't noticed this on our test sites either.

Comment: Has there been any update on this issue? I'm encountering the same error utilizing an AJAX submit with Freeform 2.0 for EE 6.2.7.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't heard this reported before and am not seeing it on our end. Can you create a support ticket for this, include more info like PHP version, etc, and we'll look into the issue there? :)

https://docs.solspace.com/expressionengine/freeform/v1/support.html

Comment: Has there been any update on this issue? I'm encountering the same error utilizing an AJAX submit with Freeform 2.0 for EE 6.2.7.